# Changing event.target.value in the onChange event, then using checkValidity() but does not work

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom

Hello I need to change the event.target.value with an input and that input has 8 character min rule.
I'm currently doing like this(example) in a component react js:

```
              <input
              ...
              minLength={8}
              onChange={(e) => {
                onChangeHandler(e);
              }}

          />
```

Where in the onChangeHandler i'm doing this

```
e.target.value = 'less8';
console.log(e.target.checkValidity());
```

However when i call checkValidity it's returning 'true', but i was expecting 'false'.

I debugged this and it's because when i assigned a value into 'e.target.value' the function 'e.target.checkValidity()' does not work anymore.

Does anyone have another way to assign a value to 'e.target.value' and still make 'checkValidity()' work?

Comment: Ah ok thanks! 


It looks like there's another attribute I can use called 'pattern' which works!


It's strange that 'minLength' does not work when using JS to simulate user interaction

Comment: Problem is I have many components that uses 'minLength', I would have to go through each one and change it to 'pattern' attribute :-(